# libcurl in C++: converting URL to some weird symbols

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, curl, libcurl

I have noticed that libcurl for C++ changes the URL provided to some weird symbols. Here is the code:

```
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

curl_handle = curl_easy_init();
cout << "http://subdomain.mydomain.com/folder/check.php?key=" + key << endl;

curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://subdomain.mydomain.com/folder/check.php?key=" + addon_key);

curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &writeCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

res = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
```

That's what I get in the console:

```
http://subdomain.mydomain.com/folder/check.php?key=tasdasm34234k23l423m4234mn23n4jk23bjk4b23nasdasdasdasdsdsd
* Rebuilt URL to: � ��g/
* IDN support not present, can't parse Unicode domains
* getaddrinfo(3) failed for �   ��g:80
* Couldn't resolve host '�  ��g'
* Closing connection 0
```

This code works perfectly fine when I build my project in Windows, but when I build it with Linux, this happens. If I just try to access "http://subdomain.mydomain.com/folder/check.php" with this code, it works, but as soon as I add the key, libcurl changes the whole URL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `addon_key`? What is its type? You know that the library is a C library with C functions that doesn't know anything about C++ objects (like `std::string`)?

Comment: It is of type std::string.

Comment: looks like your strings don't have a null terminator

Comment: @deW1, thanks for the answer. It actually helped. I am still wondering why it worked in Windows, but not in Linux.

Comment: @Alex, my guess is that it's a difference of how MSVC's `std::string` is layed out compared to GLIBC's version.  If the first `sizeof(char*)` bytes of the string object happen to be the pointer to the string's contents then passing a `std::string` to `curl_easy_setopt` could work just by coincidence.

Comment: Can you post a MWE?

Answer (score 3):

Like I said in my comment, the CURL library is a library of C functions, and C functions doesn't know anything about objects or classes from C++.

When you do `"http://subdomain.mydomain.com/folder/check.php?key=" + addon_key` the result is a (temporary) `std::string` object. Passing that to a C function will not work well, and I'm surprised that the compiler actually let you pass that argument without complaining. It should have been a compiler error I think, or at the very least should give you a stern warning.

You can solve this by creating another variable to store the string object, and the use the `c_str` member function to get a C-style string (a pointer to constant `char`):

```
std::string url = "http://subdomain.mydomain.com/folder/check.php?key=" + addon_key;
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
```

I don't know if cURL copies the string, or if you need to keep the `url` variable alive until you're all done.

That it apparently work on Windows is nothing more than pure luck. Passing a C++ object to a function that does not expect it is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: The 3rd parameter of `curl_easy_setopt()` is variadic, so the compiler *cannot* validate input in it. That is why the code can compile when passing a `std::string` where a `char*` is expected. Starting with libcurl 7.17.0, `curl_easy_setopt()` copies `char*` input (the [documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html) states this), so you don't need a `std::string` variable, you can call `c_str()` directly on a temp, eg: `curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, ("http://subdomain.mydomain.com/folder/check.php?key=" + addon_key).c_str());` though using a variable is safer